# How do I prevent the user from viewing a response from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, encryption

I want create a secure AJAX call and response from client and server.

I encrypt the AJAX request with an encryptor method and routing 
like this

```
url: "/site/web/J+CVKhtwFK9VwSZYiza8zr8YUqWK62VSkobVfgB3+1s="
```

and it's workign correctly.

My question is, when I do the AJAX call to server and get the response back, I can go into 'Network' in Google Chrome, inspect the response and view it. Like this:

```
{"d":{"__type":"unproject.Services.Services+retvalMessage","retval":"1","message":"ok"}}
```

How i can encrypt this response or prevent user from seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can pass session variable is one key for client. session is encrypct string like your string J+CVKhtwFK9VwSZYiza8zr8YUqWK62VSkobVfgB3+1s=.
 In ajax request we can check this url variable and session detect user login or not login so secure problem ok.

Comment: You can look facebook and other app in facebook it include if it use http ajax request have session key in ajax get url or post paramenter.

Comment: @ tuan huynh my purpose is sample code ro article from this subjec

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are tryng to write your own method to encrpyt the data you are sending to/from the server, in which case you need to serve the content over [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) if you really want it to be secure.

Don't try and write your own encryption if this data is important.